# a cookie from multiple variable

Tags: php, cookies

how can I store multiple variable for a variable in one cookie using php? For example variable $name, $password, $latitude, $longitude, store in one variable $seal_cookie, and then create the cookie from variable $seal_cookie. Thank you in advance.

Comment: **never store the password in a cookie. **

Answer (score 2):

Put the variables in an array, and put the array in a cookie:

```
$seal_cook = array('name'=>$name,
                   'password'=>$password,
                   'lat'=>$latitude,
                   'long'=>$longitude);
setcookie("seal_cookie", serialize($seal_cookie));
```

When you read the cookie, use `unserialize()` to get back the array.

Comment: Arrays? Shouldn't it be serialized?

Comment: You're right. For some reason I thought PHP would do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $seal_cookie="$name , $password , $latitude , $longitude";
    setcookie("seal_cookie", $seal_cookie);
?>
```

What was so tough about it?

Comment: I mean, Is it possible?